# "According to what you decided that I'm intelligence"

Tags: questions, interrogatives, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Is the sentence

> "**Based on what** did you decide that I'm intelligence"

equals to the following sentence?

> "**According to what** you decided that I'm intelligence"

If not, can you give me an example to such sentence with correct using in phrase "according to what"?

Comment: In the second, shouldn't it also be "...what *did you decide* that..."?

Comment: Or *have you decided that*. ... and it would be very unlikely for anyone to say that "I'm **intelligence**": *intelligence* is an abstract noun. You probably mean *intelligent*, the adjective.

Comment: @StoneyB : No, I think "intelligence" here is the branch of military or state security, as in "C Intelligence A".

Comment: They both sound a little awkward and unwieldy to me. How about: _**How** did you decide that..._

Comment: @VictorBazarov Then you would say "I'm *in* intelligence."

Comment: @user3169, possibly.  Not being ***in*** intelligence, I wouldn't know.

Comment: I can't get the reason for using "that" in these phrases. Also the logic is not right. "You" decided what "I" am?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the question of "intelligent" versus "intelligence"...

> On what basis did you decide I'm (in) intelligence?

or, as J.R. suggested

> How did you decide that...